# ''XXXX" is not a constructor in jasmine or "XXXX" encountered a declaration exception

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a simple .js file and I am using jasmine to try TDD approach, I have a simple problem but my test cases won't execute my javascript. I am not sure whats wrong in my javascript code setup that jasmine test suites will pass

My JS CODE:

```
    var Hamming = function(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    var hamming = new Hamming('A', 'BV');
    Hamming.prototype.compute = function() {
    //REST OF THE CODE
    }

MY JASMINE CODE TO TEST ABOVE:?

var Hamming = require('./hamming');

describe('Hamming', function () {
  var hamming = new Hamming();

  it('no difference between identical strands', function () {
    expect(hamming.compute('A', 'A')).toEqual(0);
  });

  xit('complete hamming distance for single nucleotide strand', function () {
    expect(hamming.compute('A','G')).toEqual(1);
  });

}
```

However I am getting this every time I try to run my test cases:

Failures:
1) Hamming encountered a declaration exception

Message:

> TypeError: Hamming is not a constructor

Stack:

> TypeError: Hamming is not a constructor

How do I fix my JS code so that it passes the tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Add `module.exports = Hamming;` to the end of your `hamming.js` file.

**Longer Explanation:**

In your test code you are attempting to load a module from the file `'./hamming'` in the following line:

```
var Hamming = require('./hamming');
```

However, that file is currently not exporting anything. Thus, your variable `Hamming` above contains nothing, i.e. the equivalent of `var Hamming = undefined;`. Then, in your test code, you try to create an instance from nothing when you run `var hamming = new Hamming();`, giving you the error you see.

You need to export your `Hamming` constructor at the end of your `hamming.js` file, as follows:

```
var Hamming = function(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
var hamming = new Hamming('A', 'BV');
Hamming.prototype.compute = function() {
//REST OF THE CODE
}

module.exports = Hamming; // ADD THIS *********
```

When you run the jasmine test now, it will still fail with a message something like `Expected undefined to equal 0`. But that is a "proper" failure because your `compute` function isn't currently returning `0`. (That's how TDD is supposed to work, with your newly written test initially failing.) It *does* show, however, that your code-under-test *is* being properly exported, and that your test code "sees" `Hamming` as a constructor.

You can learn the basics of node modules [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) or by googling elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help here but just a quick question, why do I have to comment and run just one test case at a time since when I call the function in my code like:
var hamming = new Hamming('GGACG', 'GGTCG');

only its corresponsing test case will execute

expect(hamming.compute('GGACG', 'GGTCG')).toEqual(1);

How do I get to execute all test cases once and without using xit, Do I need to change the way I accept input in my function?
var hamming = new Hamming('GGACG', 'GGTCG');

Comment: I can partly answer your question, but the total answer to your question is, I think, much broader than what I can say here. I think your question really requires you to learn the whole process of TDD, which I would strongly encourage you to do. A short answer to your question (if I understand it correctly), is that you _don't_ have to comment out any of the tests and only run one at a time. You can, in fact, run hundreds of tests at a time. The process of TDD, though, typically involves writing one failing test ("red light"), fixing the code-under-test to make the test pass ("green light")...

Comment: ...and then refactoring the code-under-test (sometimes referred to as "red light/green light testing"). You then move on to a second test using the same process, then a third test, etc. Thus the "development" of your code is "driven" by your "tests", thus "test driven development". A fuller explanation of that process does, as I said earlier, require you to go and study the process of TDD more in depth. I really like using Jasmine, so I think you've chosen a good tool to do this. Best of luck with your TDD learning.

Comment: What would be solution using RequireJS?